# How do i display specific results from SQL database in a HTML TABLE using select menus

Tags: php, html, sql

I've been at this for hours and i have gotten a slight break through, however i am at a stand still at the moment. I have a SQL Database that store vehicle information, such as make, model and year. What i want to do is allow users to modify the query and only display specific results.

I understand how to display all the records at once but what i want to add is when the user selects say for example the make as "Toyota" i want only that specific make to appear. I did reach some where in this, by using this code:

```
<form method="post" action=""> 
 <div id="search_query" >
     Make 
    <select name="make" size="0">
    <option value="honda">Honda</option>
  <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
  <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
    </select>

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

 </div>
 </form>     

<?php

    $db_con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

    if (!$db_con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db('my_db', $db_con);

    $make = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['make']);

    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM chjadb_vehicles WHERE v_make= '$make' ");


    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    echo "<table width= 970 border=1>
         <tr>
           <th width='120' scope='col'>Image</th>
           <th width='170' scope='col'>Details</th>
           <th width='185' scope='col'>Seller</th>
           <th width='126' scope='col'>Price</th>
         </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      { 
         echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td> <img src=" .$row['v_image']. " width =200 height = 130>" . "</td>";
           echo "<td>". $row['v_year'] . "&nbsp;" . $row['v_make'] . "&nbsp;". $row['v_model'] . "&nbsp;". $row['b_type']. "</td>";
           echo "<td>". $row['user_id'] ."</td>";
           echo "<td>". $row['v_price'] ."</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
      }
       echo "</table>";

     mysql_close($db_con);
    ?>
```

however when i run the page initially i get this error: "Notice: Undefined index: make in C:\xampp\htdocs\carhuntja.com\buy_a_car.php on line 62"

i did some research and realized that this was happening because i had no make value set, what i wish to do here is at the start of going to that page i want all vehicles to be displayed.

Comment: When you first load the page, `SELECT * FROM chjadb_vehicles` and display the values accordingly.  For filtering, why not use AJAX? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the query is being sent before the user chooses a make. To fix this, you need check that the user has actually submitted the form by enveloping your PHP code in `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` ("submit" is used because that is the `name` of your submit button).

```
//place connection code here (do not query the database yet)

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   //all of the database retrieval code
}
else
{
  $query_makes = "SELECT v_make FROM chjadb_vehicles";
  $result_makes = mysqli_query($query_makes);
  echo "Please choose a make."
  //echo opening select tag
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_makes))
  {
     //echo each option tag
  }
  //echo ending select tag
}
```

Also, you are missing a slash in the self-contained input tag.
Finally, you should use [MySQLi functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) because MySQL functions are deprecated in PHP.

Comment: Lovely! What if i wanna go a step further and display all the makes? ^_^

Comment: This should go in the else condition (i.e. form is not submitted) as shown above. Then you can post the `value` of the make menu and submit that to the database. This way if you add new makes, they will automatically be shown in the menu when the user visits the page.

Comment: Thanks for this i will edit the current code and let you guys have a look.. Really appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

1. When the page loads for the first time you need to run this query:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM chjadb_vehicles
   ```
2. You need to check if the user clicked the submit button and posted the make field, to do that use isset():

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['make']){
       $make = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['make']);
   }
   ```
3. I strongly suggest you use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) and [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**EDIT:**

First time the page loads you display all vehicles.

In your javascript you bind a onSelect evvent to the dropdown and once the user selects a make, you send an ajax request to the server and display the new results from the server, so it'll look something like that:

```
$('#search_query select').change(function(){
//get the selected option text
var selectedVal = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

//send ajax request
$.ajax( {
url : url,
type : "POST",
data : selectedVal ,
dataType : 'json',
success : function(data) {//handle returned data}
})
```

});

I suggest you take a look [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/), for a complete VIDEO tutorial on jquery.

Comment: Im going to add other elements to the design but before i do i want to get the basic functionality working

Comment: Seeing that i am a complete n00b to this where do you suggest i use jquery and ajax... Can you give me a bit more insight?